# JSON stringification turns 47 byte json string to 340mb?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var keys = [7925181,"68113227"];
var vals = {"7925181":["68113227"],"68113227":["7925181"]};

var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    temp[keys[i]] = vals[keys[i]];
}
//alert(JSON.stringify(vals).length);
alert(JSON.stringify(temp).length);
```

When I run that script in Chrome I get, after a good amount of time, an output of 340666156.

My question is...  how?

The commented out alert outputs 47. Seems to me that the second alert should yield the same result? That temp should pretty much be an exact copy of val?

The jsfiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vMMd2/

Oh - and if you want to crash your browser window (well it crashed my Google Chrome window) just add the following to the end:

```
temp.forEach(function(entry) {
    alert(temp);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `temp.length` would be 68113227...

Comment: @Passerby—length is always at least one higher than the highest index, so 681132271 + 1 = 68113228.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var keys = [7925181,"68113227"];
var vals = {"7925181":["68113227"],"68113227":["7925181"]};

var temp = {}; //  <--- !!!
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    temp[keys[i]] = vals[keys[i]];
}
//alert(JSON.stringify(vals).length);
alert(JSON.stringify(temp).length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/vMMd2/2/

You're creating a sparse array, and presumably V8 initializes all the gaps with <s>some garbage</s> <s>null</s> undefined values (thanks to [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) for checking that). It takes some time

Comment: _"initializes all the gaps with some garbage"_ - `JSON.stringify()` turns undefined array elements to `null`, so the output will be `[null,null,null,etc...]`

Comment: I would not have guessed that. That said it is surprising that it only starts to take time when you do `JSON.stringify()`. http://jsfiddle.net/4x597/ (without `JSON.stringify`) takes 0 seconds. With it (http://jsfiddle.net/4x597/1/) takes 39.5 seconds. I guess it's just an interpreter trick - don't initialize an array unless it's actually needed.

Comment: @neubert—the array is initialised when you assign the array literal to `temp`. You end up with an array with only two members, but length is always set to the highest index plus one, so you have a length of `68113228`. JSON doesn't have elisions so it puts `null` for undefined members.

Answer (score 7):

@zerkms, is right. But I also wanted to pointed out why this is happening.

```
> var temp = [];
> temp[10] = 'test';
> temp 
[ , , , , , , , , , , 'test' ]
```

As you can see, it creates 9 undefined values. I ran the above with nodejs so the null values are not showing up.

If I did JSON.stringfy() then you would see:

```
> JSON.stringify(temp)
'[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"test"]'
```

Comment: They're not objects, they're undefined.

Comment: Changed to null references.

Comment: And they aren't null references either :-S (sorry for being boring)

Comment: Hmmm I think they are. null values, references. All saved as pointer in javascript? No?

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: internally - may be, in javascript there are the reference type passed object types and value type passed primitive types

Comment: Remember that in JS there is a difference between `undefined` and `null`. But `JSON.stringify()` outputs `null` for undefined array elements, presumably because JSON doesn't have a concept of "undefined".

Comment: @AmirRAminfar—the elided members aren't null, they don't exist (i.e. they are, literally, undefined). Elisions are intended to help with array literals and sparse arrays, so `a = [,,,3]` creates an array with only one member (`a[3] == 3`) and length 4.